# How do I add these words to my video frame?

Tags: python, image-processing, text

I'd like to write these words in my video frame in multiple lines, instead of one line, how do I do that?

```
cv2.putText(frame, 'car %d motorbike %d bus %d  truck %d' % (car, motorbike, bus, truck), (500, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2.0, (0, 255, 255), 2)
```

something like this:

[image]

Edited: I already tried putting `/n`, see following script,  but does not work. It puts ? marks in between:

```
cv2.putText(frame, 'car %d \nmotorbike %d \nbus %d  \ntruck %d' % (car, motorbike, bus, truck), (500, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2.0, (0, 255, 255), 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried newlines `\n` and what does it look like now?

Comment: I put  \n  puts question mark, it does not work